# Should I have folded near the end of this tournament?

Tags: nlhe, tournament, strategy

I was playing an NLHE tournament (Merge game, table Double or Nothing - $2.20, Seats 10) and want to know if I made the right decision here.

Seat 1: $1,555 in chips
Seat 2: $1,320 in chips
Seat 3: $5,561 in chips
Seat 6: $870 in chips
Seat 8: $2,030 in chips
Seat 10: $3,664 in chips

Antes were $20, SB was $100 and BB was $200. Button was seat 6, I was seat 8 (the SB).

I got Q♣Q♠ in the hole. UTG (seat 1) went all-in for $1,535. Seats 2, 3 and 6 folded. I had $1910 left. What should I have done here?

Here's what actually happened:

> I went all-in, BB folded. Flop came AhJs5h; turn was Ts; river was 2h.
>
>  BB (who folded) showed Tc4s. UTG showed QhAs for the win.

Comment: Absolutely you are so ahead of the push range for 8 BB, you are coming into the BB, and you have them covered.  You cannot wait for the nuts.  You are blinded out in 5 orbits and you are not likely to get a better spot than this.  Short stacked you going to be facing all ins.   A call would be the same as BB is not going to treat $1535 different than $1910 in this spot.

Answer (score 4):

Critical points to consider:

1. You are on bubble and you are second biggest stack.
2. Player with a lower stack just went all-in having **5 players** in front of him
3. In double or nothing all winners get same reward ammount

What this should tell you:

1. You should avoid any play which risks loosing a whole stack
2. Opponent has something really strong
3. There is no need to fight for more chips, you just need to survive the bubble

Let's sum up: you really shouldn't have done that.

Answer (score 2):

No it seems pretty fine to me. You have 10bb so your in fold or shove territory anyway and if your not going to shove QQ are you really going to wait for AA on such a short stack? To be honest you were just unlucky.

If you were much deeper stacked you could consider a fold since your more interested in getting to the money spots. For example if your were 100bb deep and he shoved for 80bb you could fold here because even if he holds AK its a coin flip and why throw your tourney away on a coin flip?

Since he is short 8bb and the pot with antes is around 2.5bb dead money he could be shoving any pair 22+, suited high cards Kx, Ax and you crush most of this range.

Comment: Ty m8 thought I was about right

Comment: You're right, it's a +EV call, doesn't matter that you lost. Given how short he is, you'll usually be ahead of his pre-flop shoving range...

Comment: It's a double or nothing and it's the bubble. Not sure about the answer

Comment: I agree in general that a call with QQ is reasonable, but in this specific situation it was not. +EV has to take a back seat to the bubble.